# Does PostgreSQL `CLUSTER` command also cluster extended storage?

Tags: postgresql, clustered-index

I'm trying to improve the locality of my data by using the `CLUSTER` [command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-cluster.html) to periodically cluster records that share the same `user_id`.  My most important data is in `extended` storage.  Will extended storage be clustered also?

Comment: While `TOAST` tables do get rewritten during a `CLUSTER`, I'm not sure how much good that will do in practice. It's still out-of-line, not in the table.

Answer (score 0):

`cluster` command is a table rewrite process. So, yes it will cluster anything on the table, including `extended` storage.